# Why xdg-open won't launch mplayer when started from within Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I have my ubuntu 20.04 system set up so that `xdg-open` launches `mplayer`
for .mp4 files.

When I type

```
xdg-open ~/video.mp4
```

in the shell in terminal, `xdg-open` launches mplayer and the video plays.

But when I type;

```
:!xdg-open ~/video.mp4
```

in Neovim command line, `xdg-open` returns with exit code 0, but no video
plays (either because xdg-open doesn't launch mplayer, or mplayers quits
without playing the video).

I am confused, because `xdg-open` works fine when run from Neovim for other
file types (images open in eog, pdfs in evince, etc...).

When I run

```
:!mplayer ~/video.mp4
```

from Neovim command line, it plays the video just fine.

Furthermore, Neovim's
`gx` command from `Netrw` plugin successfully plays the video, but when I look at
the relevant `Netrw` code, it just runs `!xdg-open`!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `:terminal xdg-open …`?

Comment: No, `:terminal xdg-open ~/video.mp4` also fails to play the video. On the other hand, if I start terminal session inside Neovim with `:terminal` and then type `xdg-open ~/video.mp4` at `bash` prompt, then the video does play.